# Injecting a global helper into all underscore templates with Marionette

Tags: marionette, view-helpers, underscore.js-templating

This was originally the second part of [an other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23922288/marionette-renderer-underscore-templates-and-internationalization-with-i18next) which I was able to isolate into it's own question for better search indexing. It might be helpful to refer to it for more specific context.

My question is : **How to elegantly inject a global view helper into all underscore templates**

This questions finds it's inspiration directly from [i18next documentation](http://i18next.com/pages/doc_templates.html). It is too late in the project to switch to handlebars templates but I, by far, prefer the way it is handled with the `registerHelper` style.
Searching on that side, I came across [Derick Bailey's View Helpers article](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/26/view-helpers-for-underscore-templates/), which, as usual, provide a very neat solution to an inelegant problem.

In our architecture, we decided to re-implement serializeData for all our views and not rely on the default implementation (exporting all the attributes from the model the view is bound with). My take on this one is if I wanted to get anything close to the registerHelper style, I would have to extend the base `Marionette.View` class and provide a basic helper that is injected into all the views, by inheritance.
This doesn't seem even close to the cleanliness of handlebars helpers, giving it working at all, which at this point seems nothing but certain.

Providing any examples or any hints on which path to follow to tackle this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

**[edit]**

I found a solution to this exact problem, detailed in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23922288/marionette-renderer-underscore-templates-and-internationalization-with-i18next).
Simon also posted an answer that is also likely to work nicely.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Marionette, but Lodash (a drop-in replacement for Underscore, and the two may be merged eventually) supports this. For example, `_.templateSettings.imports = { foo: function () { ... } };` defines a new function `foo()` that can be used in any template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just use Handlebars with Marionette? You can use any template library you like. Check out [this](https://github.com/asciidisco/Backbone.Marionette.Handlebars) or write your own integration based on the Marionette [docs](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.renderer.md). I've done this myself to integrate DustJS with Marionette.

**EDIT**

Something that could work nicely is creating a `templateHelpers` property on the underscore object. Then you could do something like:

```
<span><%= _.templateHelpers.someHelper(data) %></span>
```

Comment: Like I said it is a bit too late in the project, we already have more than half a hundred templates and views relying on underscore. But I actually found a neat solution overriding Marionette.Renderer to inject the translation function.
I'm testing the implementation right now and I will probably post it as a response if it fits all the puposes!
Thanks

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I missed that part of your post.

Comment: @Mikechaos I added an extra suggestion for you.

Comment: Oh I didn't think about that at all. It is not the solution I went for (see my edit) but I will upvote as it is a solution that could potentially work nice and clean!

Comment: I've come to use your answer in a part of the application where we didn't use neither backbone nor marionette. Injecting a view helper would have been much more trouble than extending underscore the way you did! As so, I'll mark as accepted.

For an appropriate response, using Marionette, I still suggest [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23922288/marionette-renderer-underscore-templates-and-internationalization-with-i18next) approach.

Thank you